# Change footer image based on current bookmark or page number (XSL FO)

Tags: image, footer, xsl-fo

I want to change the footer image dynamically, based on a current bookmark in the page and current page number in XSL FO.

Currently I am using the code below to print the static image, but I have four images which should be dynamically changed in the common footer region.

```
<fo:external-graphic src="images/Icon.png" content-height="27mm" content-width="20mm" />
```

Comment: <fo:external-graphic src="images/Icon.png" content-height="27mm" content-width="20mm" />

Comment: What are the conditions under which one image should be used instead of the other ones?

Comment: What happens when there is more than one bookmark on the page?  Which formatter are you using?

Comment: I have style like bookmark1 and bookmark2, I want to diplay Icon.png when current bookmark is bookmark1 when I navigate to bookmark2 image in footer should change to Icon2.png. Also let me know instead of bookmark1 based on current page number can we change the image?